# If a matrix in $SO(4)$ preserves complex lines, then it is complex linear

Tags: linear-algebra, geometry, linear-transformations

If $X\in SO(4)$, then we know that it's continuous, bijective, and origin-fixing. It also is real-linear.

If we also assume that it maps a complex line $\{t(a,b,c,d):t\in \mathbb C\}$ (where $\mathbb C^2\cong \mathbb R^4$) to another complex line, then can we conclude that $X$ is complex-linear as well?

The only thing to check is that $X(\lambda(a,b,c,d))=\lambda X(a,b,c,d)$ for every $\lambda \in \mathbb C$, but I have had no luck.

Comment: possibly relevant https://www3.nd.edu/~andyp/notes/FunThmProjGeom.pdf

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think the transformation

$$ X=\begin{pmatrix} 1&0&0&0\\0&-1&0&0\\0&0&1&0\\0&0&0&-1 \end{pmatrix} $$

preserves complex lines, but isn't complex linear. We have $X(\lambda v) = \bar{\lambda} X(v)$, so

$$ L=\{ \lambda v | \lambda \in \mathbb{C} \} \mapsto X(L) = \{ \bar{\lambda}X(v) | \lambda \in \mathbb{C} \} = \{\lambda X(v) | \lambda \in \mathbb{C} \},$$

and $X$ preserves complex lines, unless I missed something.

---

The inspiration here is that complex conjugation preserves complex lines, but isn't complex linear.

Comment: I meant that requirement is the only to check for in order to see if $X$ is complex linear. I'm not sure what you mean by it's not the right think to ask for.

Comment: Oh, sorry, somehow I misunderstood you.